# index 22 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python

I am  trying to convert the following  matlab code to pyhton and want to print em1. Howvever I am getting the following traceback error. When I tried to print I_1 , it works  but when I  tried  to print em1, the code shows an error

Answer (score 0):

Main problems are:

- `Im` test array isn't big enough for the test indices
- Need to call `Im.flat` to access via index

Here is some example code that should help clear things up more elegantly:

```
import numpy as np

x0 = np.array([[5, 6], [3, 5]])
y0 = np.array([[9, 10], [4, 1]])

Im = np.random.normal(0, 1, (36, 36))

I_1 = np.ravel_multi_index(
    ((x0.flatten() + 1).astype(np.int64),
     (y0.flatten() + 1).astype(np.int64),)
    , dims=Im.shape, order='F')

em1 = Im.flat[I_1]
```